# Names of subcontrols in WPF UserControl cannot be registered after drag-and-drop

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a solution with a WPF control library - with some UserControls in it - and a WPF application which shall use the UserControls from the library.
I added the library as project reference.
In the WPF application i have two WPF Windows.
One with the controls (like a TooBox) and another one, to which i want to Transfer/copy the controls by drag-and-drop.
When i drop one of my UserControls on the second window, i get a string with the xaml from dragged element by usage of XamlDesignerSerializationManager.
Then i try to create a FrameworkElement out of the XAML-string using StringReader and XmlReader.
At this Point i get a System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException because the Name "border" - which i use in the UserControl XAML - exists twice and cannot be registered.

Can anybody explain why this happens?

Here the XAML for one of the UserControls:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfDesignerControlLibrary.ControlLabel"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfDesignerControlLibrary"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="30"
             d:DesignWidth="150">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border Name="border"
                Style="{StaticResource usercontrolBorderStyle}">
            <Label Name="label"
                   Margin="2">
                <TextBlock Name="textblock"
                           Text="Label"
                           TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            </Label>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

What i get from the XamlDesignerSerializationManager when serializing the dragged control:

```
<ControlLabel Text="Label" ControlHorizontalContentAlignment="Left" ControlVerticalContentAlignment="Top" FontIsBold="True" FontStyleIsItalic="False" TextIsUnderlined="False" FontWeight="Bold" Name="label21" av:Canvas.Left="103" av:Canvas.Top="214" xmlns="clr-namespace:WpfDesignerControlLibrary;assembly=WpfDesignerControlLibrary" xmlns:av="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <ControlLabel.TextDecorations>
    <av:TextDecorationCollection />
  </ControlLabel.TextDecorations>
  <av:Grid>
    <av:Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <av:ColumnDefinition />
    </av:Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <av:Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <av:RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </av:Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <av:Border Name="border">
      <av:Border.Style>
        <av:Style TargetType="av:IFrameworkInputElement">
          <av:Style.Resources>
            <av:ResourceDictionary />
          </av:Style.Resources>
          <av:Setter Property="av:Border.BorderBrush">
            <av:Setter.Value>
              <av:SolidColorBrush>#FF4169E1</av:SolidColorBrush>
            </av:Setter.Value>
          </av:Setter>
          <av:Setter Property="av:Border.BorderThickness">
            <av:Setter.Value>
              <av:Thickness>1,1,1,1</av:Thickness>
            </av:Setter.Value>
          </av:Setter>
          <av:Setter Property="av:FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment">
            <av:Setter.Value>
              <x:Static Member="av:HorizontalAlignment.Stretch" />
            </av:Setter.Value>
          </av:Setter>
          <av:Setter Property="av:FrameworkElement.VerticalAlignment">
            <av:Setter.Value>
              <x:Static Member="av:VerticalAlignment.Stretch" />
            </av:Setter.Value>
          </av:Setter>
        </av:Style>
      </av:Border.Style>
      <av:Label Name="label" Margin="2,2,2,2">
        <av:TextBlock Text="Label" TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="textblock" />
      </av:Label>
    </av:Border>
  </av:Grid>
</ControlLabel>
```

This is the method with which i get the XAML as string out of the dragged control:

```
public string SerializeControlToXaml(FrameworkElement control)
{
    StringBuilder outstr = new StringBuilder();

    //this code need for right XML fomating 
    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.Indent = true;
    settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
    XamlDesignerSerializationManager dsm =
        new XamlDesignerSerializationManager(XmlWriter.Create(outstr, settings));
    //this string need for turning on expression saving mode 
    dsm.XamlWriterMode = XamlWriterMode.Expression;
    System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter.Save(control, dsm);

    string xaml = outstr.ToString();
    return xaml;
}
```

And at last the method which produces the error (in the last line of code):

```
public object DeserializeXaml(string xaml)
{
    StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xaml);
    XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
    return System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it out.
You have to remove all names from the UserControl-definition and use a ViewModel.